# How to get the name of the WiFi network to which my Raspberry Pi in my program

Tags: raspbian, wifi

I'm looking for a way to identify the WiFi network to which my Raspberry Pi is connected in my program (Python) so that I can use the name of the WiFi.

Answer (score 5):

From the command line

```
iwgetid
```

will give you the ssid of the active wlan. More config information can also be seen with

```
iwconfig
```

You can parse this data and use it in your program to display wlan info.

Comment: See also `iw link` (e.g., `iw wlan0 link`).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the iproute2 command `iw` to get to which your rpi is connected:

```
iw dev <interface> link | grep SSID | awk '{print $2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

`iwconfig` may help (man page: https://linux.die.net/man/8/iwconfig). When called with an interface name `iwconfig wlan0` it should print the current information, which also includes the ESSID -- the network name.

You may need to "sanitize" the network name when you plan to use it as a hostname: hostnames should be conforming to DNS label rules, and only consist of letters, digits, and hyphens, with some additional constraints applied (so-called LDH rule). In particular, you need to remove blanks, dots, underscores, and many ASCII characters.